# How to convert string length?

Tags: c#, .net, string, substring

i have char(10) field (it is Persian date field) in my database. my control in c# for some date creates char(8). then i have problem in store procedure(where date between dateFrom and DateTo). i must have char(10). i want to write function in c# to check the string and if the it's length is less than 10 convert it to 10. my format is yyyy/mm/dd. (yyyy has no problem in my control)
for example i want to convert 1391/1/1 to 1391/01/01 
please help me how i can insert 0 and check the number after /.

Comment: can you tell me how you are taking date by using ajax calender or jquery calendar or any other format

Comment: @Ramakrishna.p i have a dll.(persian calender)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved.

```
public  static string ConvertToDate(string persianDate)
    {
        try
        {
            if (persianDate.Length != 10)
            {
                char a = Convert.ToChar(persianDate.Substring(4, 1));
                char b = Convert.ToChar(persianDate.Substring(6, 1));
                if (a == '/' && b == '/')
                {
                    if (persianDate.Length == 9)
                    {
                        persianDate = persianDate.Insert(5, '0'.ToString());
                    }
                    if (persianDate.Length == 8)
                    {
                        persianDate = persianDate.Insert(5, '0'.ToString());
                        persianDate = persianDate.Insert(8, '0'.ToString());
                    }


                }
                char c = Convert.ToChar(persianDate.Substring(7, 1));
                if (c == '/')
                {
                    if (persianDate.Length == 9)
                    {
                        persianDate = persianDate.Insert(8, '0'.ToString());
                    }

                }

            }
            return persianDate;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           ExceptionkeeperBll.LogFileWrite(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like the following.

```
string[] words = date.Split('/');
if (words[1].Length == 1)
{
  words[1]="0"+words[1];
} 

if (words[2].Length == 1)
{
  words[2]="0"+words[2];
} 

string newDate = words[0] + "/" + words[1] + "/" + words[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime res;
string input = "1391/1/1";
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "yyyy/M/d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out res))
{
    string toDb = res.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"); //1391/01/01

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure `InvariantCulture` is right here, considering it's Persian date.

Answer (score 0):

**Available Date formats**
**Choose accordingly**

```
<%= String.Format("{specifier}", DateTime.Now) %>

Specifier   Description Output
d   Short Date             08/04/2007
D   Long Date              08 April 2007
t   Short Time             21:08
T   Long Time              21:08:59
f   Full date and time     08 April 2007 21:08
F   Full date and time (long)  08 April 2007 21:08:59
g   Default date and time      08/04/2007 21:08
G   Default date and time (long)08/04/2007 21:08:59
M   Day / Month            08 April
r   RFC1123 date               Sun, 08 Apr 2007 21:08:59 GMT
s   Sortable date/time     2007-04-08T21:08:59
u   Universal time, local timezone  2007-04-08 21:08:59Z
Y   Month / Year               April 2007
dd  Day                    08
ddd Short Day Name             Sun
dddd    Full Day Name      Sunday
hh  2 digit hour               09
HH  2 digit hour (24 hour)     21
mm  2 digit minute             08
MM  Month                      04
MMM Short Month name       Apr
MMMM    Month name     April
ss  seconds                    59
tt  AM/PM                      PM
yy  2 digit year               07
yyyy    4 digit year       2007
:   seperator, e.g. {0:hh:mm:ss}    09:08:59
/   seperator, e.g. {0:dd/MM/yyyy}  08/04/2007
```